# AWS LogInsights query stats average of count

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have cloudwatch entries that may be group with respect to a certain field. To be clear assume that field is city. I would like to count the entries with respect to cities. This is the easy part.

```
fields city
|stats count(*) by city
```

However I also want to get maximum minimum and average of this count, but I can not. Is it possible to have such queries i.e:

```
fields city
|stats avg(count(*) by city)
```

The console return an error  for such query : mismatched input 'by' expecting {SYM_COMMA, SYM_RParen}

Comment: Were you able to solve that at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd do it: You'd first get the count (that you already figured) and then get the metrics you want by calling the relevant functions like so:

```
fields city
|stats count(*) as cityCount, avg(cityCount), max(cityCount), min(cityCount)
```